# How many parameters is optimal for constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, oop, mvvm-light

I have a C# project that needs to refactor. Project uses WPF+MVVM Light toolkit. I found the `MainViewModel(...)` constructor that receives about 50 parameters (factories interfaces). I think not. Am I right? I'm interested, because I want to improve my OOP thinking. Thanks.

P.S. Sorry for my grammar. Check me if you find errors.

Comment: 50 Parameters is way too much. Follow [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and you won't have this question at all. Btw your question is subjective and thus not suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you want someone to tell you "Oh, N parameters is pretty good, but N+1 is too much"? I think it is very opinion-based.

Comment: @Andy Korneyev It is not only my opinion or someone else. I need to know "rules" of clean OOP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50 factory interfaces means your ViewModel is way too big and trying to do too many things at the same time. You should break it into separate ViewModels that will appear as properties on the main view model.

WPF allows composition and any framework that allows ViewModel first (ie anything except PRISM) will compose the corresponding views form the ViewModel it encounters. I'm not sure about MVVM Light but with Caliburn.Micro this is almost a non-issue.

If MVVM Light doesn't automate this, you'll have to bind the WPF controls that will contain a specific child model's view to the child model property on the main view model.

Another option is to bundle multiple factory interfaces into parameter objects and pass these to the constructor, bringing the number of parameters to 4-5 instead of 50. This is the [Introduce Parameter Object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object) refactoring. Some tools like ReSharper provide automation support for this refactoring.

If you combine this with a DI container the parameter objects can get initialized automagically simply by registering the individual interfaces.

The best solution though is to break the main model into submodels

Answer (score 3):

[Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), page 40, states that...

> The ideal number of arguments for a function is zero (niladic). Next comes one (monadic), followed closely by two (dyadic). Three arguments (triadic) should be avoided where possible. More than three (polyadic) requires very special justification - and then shouldn't be used anyway.

Consider the book as guidelines for software design, and as such, recommendations when thinking about your code structure.

Answer (score -2):

You might look into using a Dependency Injector like Unity.  Register all your Service, Factory, and associated Classes you need with the Unity Container and then you only need a single parameter for your ViewModel constructor which is the Unity Container.

50 parameters for a constructor seems insane to me...

Comment: But wouldn't this mean that he needs to resolve the factories in the constructor (or when needed), thus hiding the dependencies from an observer (someone looking at the constructor signature)?

Comment: That's the service-locator antipattern. The classes should never have to know about the DI container. The problem here is how to get rid of the 50 dependencies, not hard code them as DI calls inside the constructor

Comment: Without looking at his code we have no real idea how to fix things.  For all we know this ViewModel is getting things in his constructor and passing them to other ViewModel Constructors.  Using a DI container at least lets you have manageable constructor parameters while you fix up the mess...

Comment: DI container yes. Passing the container itself to the objects - no. This simply covers up the problem and introduces yet another dependency. That's why service locator is considered an anti-pattern. In any case, DI solves a different problem. This particular problem (too many parameters) is solved by the [parameter object refactoring](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object)

Comment: The problem is calling it a DI "container" which lends to the idea that it's a box containing lots of different objects - which can really only be used as a service locator. What you need is an *injector*. Uses introspection to provide object requirements *on-build*.